# evaluation sequence of `switch` in `go`

Tags: go

I am learning Go language by reading "Effective Go".

I found a example about type switch:

```
var t interface{}
t = functionOfSomeType()
switch t := t.(type) {
default:
    fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T\n", t)     // %T prints whatever type t has
case bool:
    fmt.Printf("boolean %t\n", t)             // t has type bool
case int:
    fmt.Printf("integer %d\n", t)             // t has type int
case *bool:
    fmt.Printf("pointer to boolean %t\n", *t) // t has type *bool
case *int:
    fmt.Printf("pointer to integer %d\n", *t) // t has type *int
}
```

My understanding is the cases in `switch` is evaluated from top to bottom and stop at a match condition. So isn't the example about would always stop at `default` and print "unexpected type ..."?

Comment: No. Take a look at the chapter "Type Switches" in the language spec.

Comment: @Volker The selection of the default case is actually only explained in "Expression switches".

Comment: @Rhymoid: "[Switch statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements): Type switches: A type switch compares types rather than values. It is otherwise similar to an expression switch." Therefore you should have read the specification for expression switches too.

Comment: @peterSO Aside from the questionable structuring of the Go language spec, I believe that an answer, or a comment pretending to be one, should be at least as specific as the question. Referring to the paragraph that doesn't define what the OP is asking about wouldn't suffice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this Golang tutorial](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/control-structures-go-switch-case.html):

- The code block of `default` is executed if none of the other `case` blocks match
- the `default` block can be anywhere within the `switch` block, and not necessarily last in lexical order